# Is it possible to extend the height and width of a child element beyond its container?

Tags: javascript, vector, svg

I have a zoomable svg that's provided by 3rd a party API. It's basically a drawing that's mapped to a grid. The problem is the API doesn't include the grid in the provided svg file so I have to hack it to include one. Basically, the markup is like this:

```
<svg>
  <g>
    <line>....
    <rect>....
    etc...
  </g>
</svg>
```

The zoom functionality is done and now I'd like to add the grid. I'm thinking I should add it like so:

```
<svg>
  <g>
     <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="black" />
     <defs>
         <pattern id="grid" width="20" height="20" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
           <path d="M 1 1 L 0 0 0 0" fill="none" stroke="green" stroke-width="1" />
         </pattern>
     </defs>
     <rect x="-100%" y="-100%" width="200%" height="200%" fill="url(#grid)" />
    <line>....
    <rect>....
    etc...
  </g>
</svg>
```

The grid is drawn but it's bound within the `<g>` tag. Is it possible to extend the grid beyond it but still zoomable? Or are there other better ways to achieve this?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "bound within the `<g>` tag"?  A demo (eg a jsfiddle) - or at least a screenshot - would be useful.

Comment: BTW, it is not the group element that is determining the size of the grid, it is the rect.